# CSS Header Background-Color Won't Work

Tags: html, css, header

I've been able to change the background-color for the entire page, but am struggling to change the header's separate background-color. Any help would be epic:[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T4jdq)

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="header" border="0">
    <div id="header_button" alt="Ashley Lincoln Designs">
    enter code here`<img src="images/logo.png" height="100px"><div>
    <div id="header_button">About</div>
    <div id="header_button">Newest<br>Project</div>
    <div id="header_button">Archive</div>
    <div id="header_button">Contact</div>
</div>

<p>Test</p>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #174C4F;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FSE9BE;
}

#header_button {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    color: #207178;
    font-family: "Verdana", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-indent: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #FSE9BE;
}
```

Comment: i saw your code in fiddle, you really need to learn html and css, you have done so many mistakes in your small piece of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is your IDs aren't unique (they should be, by the HTML standard). Use a class - see here http://jsfiddle.net/T4jdq/1/

```
<div class="header_button">About</div>
<div class="header_button">Newest<br>Project</div>
<div class="header_button">Archive</div>
<div class="header_button">Contact</div>

.header_button {
    height: 100px;
    ...
    background-color: red;
}
```

As for lining up the buttons - there's a lot you can do with navigation bars. I'm not quite sure what you want; the the example nav bar has the image above everything else. If you add `float: left;` to the other elements they line up. Other than that, it's a matter of a lot of tweaking :P . I recommend using Chrome and the dev console (right click, inspect element) which lets you modify the CSS live.

Answer (score 2):

You have the CSS mostly correct, but your `#header` background color isn't a valid HEX color. Presently it's set to:

```
background-color: #FSE9BE;
```

It should be

```
background-color: #F5E9BE;
```

Note qr ***S*** tu is not the same as 34 ***5*** 67

As others have mentioned, you can only use `id` once per page. Your `header_button`s are better suited to `class`.

As for making the menu items all align better;

simply add:

```
vertical-align:top;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/T4jdq/2/

Answer (score 1):

Updated the fiddle:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T4jdq/3/)

```
<body>
<div id="header" border="10">
    <img src="Images/logo.png" id="header_button" alt="Some Text"/>
    <div id="header_button" alt="Ashley Lincoln Designs"/>
    <div id="header_button">About</div>
    <div id="header_button">Newest<br>Project</div>
    <div id="header_button">Archive</div>
    <div id="header_button">Contact</div>
</div>

<p style="position:relative">Test</p>

</body>
```

Css:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #174C4F;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:Black;
}

#header_button {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    color: #207178;
    font-family: "Verdana", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-indent: 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: #FSE9BE;
}
```

and I agree with @DaCrosby.. The HEX decimal for color was invalid. Everything is fine then.

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5TpAD/)

Css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}
body{
    background-color: #174C4F;
}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: red;
}

.header_button {
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    color: #207178;
    font-family: "Verdana", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-indent: 0px;}
```

html

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="header_button"> <img src="images/logo.png"
        height="100px" alt="Ashley Lincoln Design"s /></div>
 <div>
    <div class="header_button">About</div>
 <div class="header_button"> Newest 
     <br/>Project

</div>
    <div class="header_button">Archive</div>
    <div class="header_button">Contact</div>
</div>

<p>Test</p>
```